# transparent widgets inside transparent frame pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a problem solving an issue for my program. When I create a transparent Widget that holds some other widgets, they become transparent too and I don't understand why.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFixedSize(860, 560)

        # Set the opacity
        self.setWindowOpacity(1 - 50 / 100)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton("TEST"))
```

In this sample code, the widget QPushButton will appear transparent, it's the same with labels, and other widgets. How do I apply transparency ONLY to my class MainFrame.

Edit :

here is what I have (transparent button and transparent QWidget) :
[image]
here is what I need (NO transparent button and transparent QWidget) :
[image]
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

The full code adapted from your example is this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainFrame(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setFixedSize(860, 560)

        # Set the opacity
        #self.setWindowOpacity(1 - 50 / 100)

        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton("TEST"))

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Frame = MainFrame(None)
    Frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```

, and the result is this:

[image: transparent QWidget]

If you want to have only some transparency you might need to rewrite the `paintEvent` like in [this example](https://wiki.qt.io/QWidget_Semi-transparent_Background_Color).

Comment: Hi, thanks but this is not exactly what I need, I still need the transparent widget (not totally transparent). I edited my question.

Comment: @Darkos As I said at the end of my answer: If you need partial transparency than you need to re-implement the paintEvent. The way you have to do it is in the link at the bottom.

Comment: You are perfectly right ! I didn't try, Thank you very much.